# Low level implementation of bitwise Mod

Tags: c++, c, bit-manipulation, modulus

It has come to notice that when modding

```
(mod(x, n))
```

we would prefer to make n a power of 2. How does this help and is this faster?

Comment: suggested answers exploits the fact that the binary representation of an integer modular 2^k is just the trailing part of that of the integer, but be careful, it only works on unsigned integers and signed integers with 2's complement.

Answer (score 4):

Your "question" is rather vague, but as a guess is this what you are looking for?

```
x & (n-1)
```

where `n` is a power of 2. This will give you `x % n`.

Answer (score 2):

Envision the bits:

```
Let n = (1000)2 = 8
```

So if you want to know the remainder of `X / n`, you just need to know if there are any values in the 3 spots below the power of 2:

```
Let X = (1111)2 = 15
          ^^^ .... these will be the remainder
```

So if you pick some power of 2, and subtract 1 from it, you get all the bits set for anything below it:

```
n - 1 = (1000)2 - (0001)2 = (0111)2
```

Looking at X now:

```
  X     = (1111)2
& n - 1 = (0111)2
------------------
        = (0111)2
```

Since bit wise operations can be done **very** fast, and division operations are relatively slow, this type of modulo is much faster than doing a division.

Answer (score 0):

modding by a power of 2 is an & (bitwise AND) operator.

mod(x,2^k) = x & U

where U = ((2^k)-1), which is a constant.

otherwise, you have to divide and find the remainder.  bitwise AND is typically 1 clock cycle to execute, whereas divide is much slower.  The details of this has to do with the logic implementation of & versus %.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question of **why it is better**... `mod(x,y)` pretty much costs as much as integer division.  Much more than a simple `AND` operation (depending on your hardware division may cost several CPU cycles).

Slightly off topic, but definitely in an FPGA (verilog / VHDL) the AND operation results in using much much less hardware than division.

Answer (score 0):

A div command in assembler (using to calculate mod) is much more expensive from shift command.

usually: 1 div = 4 shifts.

a div with power of two can be replaced by a shift.

```
n=2 -> shift by 1,  mod = i & 1  
n=4 -> shift by 2,  mod = i & 3
```

or generally for any int i

```
n=2^i -> shift by i, mod = x & ((2^i)-1)
```